# GNU coreutils on SMB shares results in "Operation not supported"

Tags: permission, smb, macos

When I try to move files on a Windows 10 SMB share using `mv` from the GNU coreutils Homebrew package I get "Operation not supported"

When manually using `/bin/mv` instead it works perfectly.

I have already tried giving `gmv` the `Full Disk Access` permission in the Privacy panel. But that makes no difference either.

Some more details:

- I'm running OS X 12.4 Monterey, but I noticed the same behaviour in OS X 11 Big Sur.
- The server is running Windows 10
- Moving works using `/bin/mv`
- Moving works using Finder

Comment: I've also observed this with a TrueNAS (Samba) smbfs share, so it's not specific to the remote server being Windows 10.